# HTMLPurifier converts > to &gt;

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using HTMLPurifier with an input textarea where users are allowed to put their HTML tag. Config is default:

```
        $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
        $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
        $_POST['txt'] = $purifier->purify($_POST['txt']);
```

The problem I am getting is when the users put some `>` in the text, for example:

```
<p>Some text > other text </p>
```

This gets converted to:

```
<p>Some text &gt; other text </p>
```

Is there any way to stop that conversion? Without doing the oblivious:

```
$_POST['txt'] = str_replace('&gt;','>',$_POST['txt']);
```

Comment: If this conversion oesn't happen, the HTML will be invalid. If that's what you want, there may be a config option for that.

Comment: @MichaelMior: your comment could be an answer

Comment: @latink Posted as an answer in case that solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this conversion doesn't happen, the HTML will be invalid. If that's what you want, there may be a config option for that.

Answer (score 1):

as you probably know `&gt;` html special character for `>`. Browser will render everything properly.

You can try using [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode all special chars to original values.